# Background image not appearing on div when including Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, Bootstrap is messing with the background image on a div.

html code:

```
<div class="wide">
  <div class="col-xs-5 line">
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 line">
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 1px);
  background-image: url(http://wp.df.uba.ar/sociofis/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2016/08/Epidemias4.png);
  background-color: #ccccc1;  /* Color if image unavailable */
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.line {
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.line hr {
  border-color: #000;
}
```

[JSFiddle including Bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/jkLvkdy6/).

[JSFiddle **not** including Bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/onqtps98/1/).

I'm trying to replicate [this example](http://www.bootply.com/108614) but to no avail. It's not a problem of jsfiddle as by copying and pasting the exact same code to a [new jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2e12cnov/) it works with no issues.

Apparently the problem is in the image itself. With the image on the original example the background loads correctly and with the one I'm testing it doesn't.

Comment: Thumbs up for providing the detail and JSFiddle to make troubleshooting this real easy! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<body>` element has a height of zero, and your .wide element is using `height: calc(100% - 1px)` which means `100%` of `0 - 1px` is `-1px`.

Give your body element a height of 100%...

https://jsfiddle.net/w6y2nrfy/

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the image proportions on the wide element expanding your solution on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6y2nrfy/1/)